# Discord.js Bot -- How to check every day which day is

Tags: discord, discord.js

i want to make a bot that every day checks if its the birthday of a member. But i dont know how to check everyday's day.

Im writting my bot with node.js.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with `Date` a built in feature of node.js. [Date Docs](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)
For today's date: `10th of August`

```
function getToday(){
    let today = new Date();
    let months = [`January`,`February`,`March`,`April`,`May`,`June`,`July`,`August`,`September`,`October`,`November`,`December`];
    let suffix = [`st`,`nd`,`rd`];
    return `${today.getDate()}${suffix[today.getDate()] || `th`} of ${months[today.getMonth()]}`;
}
console.log(getToday());
```

Comment: But how can i call this function every new day?. I want my bot to check if "today" is any event that i have in a list

Comment: `setInterval(CHECKER_FUNTION,86400000)` Would run `CHECKER_FUNCTION` every 24 hours... Or you could just check the date every time a message is sent.